# Powershell script to copy file's content and paste it into a different file

Tags: powershell

I want to write a PowerShell Script to copy the content of a text file and paste it into another existing text file.
I have two text files. The first file1 has domain names and I wanna copy the domain names and and add '*' at the beginning of each domain then paste it to file2.

Note: File2 already has domain names, so when I copy from file1 I don't want to overwrite the content of file2.

Say the content of file1,

```text
thunderbolt
bakery
```

When the content is copied into file2 it should look something like this,

```text
thunderbolt
*thunderbolt
bakery
*bakery
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I helped you with the formatting. Could you please insert a sample of file 2 before pasting the content of file 1?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
$file1Lines = Get-Content -Path "file1"
foreach ($file1Line in $file1Lines)
{

    $file1Line | Out-File -FilePath "file2" -Append
    "*$($file1Line)" | Out-File -FilePath "file2" -Append
}
```

I would make the paths to file1 and file2 variables, and make sure file2 is deleted if it already exists at the beginning